# TextMate: Highlight from cursor to beginning or end of line?

Tags: macos, editor, syntax-highlighting, textmate

In TextMate, how do I highlight from my cursor position to the beginning or the end of a line?

Normally I can do this in gui text editors on the mac (or in form textareas, etc) by:

Shift-Cmd-LeftArrow (highlight from here to beginning of line) or

Shift-Cmd-RightArrow (from here to end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was. A re-download and reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Those shortcuts work fine for me. Maybe you've changed the key bindings for TextMate?

Comment: Nope. I just installed it and the only thing I changed was the theme. Maybe I'll reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an OS-wide solution:

http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/

-- Keith